# Can a WPF app with .sdf database run on a computer without SQL Server installed

Tags: sql-server, wpf

This question may seems a bit silly. The thing is I'm programming a WPF using VS2010, which contains a `.sdf` database (connection is ADO.NET).

Someone told me that if I use a SQL Server Express database it can be run on any PC even it has no SQL Server installed. But after I tried executing in my virtual machine (win7 & win xp), seems it cannot even start up.

So, can someone brief me, what database do people normally use in developing WPF software? Is it true that my program using a SQL Server database file cannot execute on PC without SQL Server installed?

Much appreciate in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it can**!

SQL Server Compact (that produces and uses `.sdf`) is the only SQL Server edition that **does not require** a server to be installed. All its code and logic is contained in the handful of DLL's that you need to include with your application. Just ship your app with those DLL's and you should be fine.

[Read more about SQL Server Compact and how to use and deploy it on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

SQL Server **Express** (and any of the other editions, like Web, Standard, Developer, Enterprise) on the other hand **does require** an installation of the SQL Server Express edition - either on that machine, or somewhere in the network where your app runs (remote connections from the network are disabled by default, but can be enabled).

Comment: Thank you very much marc! It did helped a lot!